Selenium doesn't pick the right MUI-X Datepicker (SSR related bug?)
I encountered a problem using codeception with selenium. I tried to write an acceptance test for some forms and with codeception using selenium. But i'm struggling with the MUI-X Datepickers.
The Datepickers comes in 2 variants, mobile and desktop. Depending on the media query, it will show one of them.
I used that attribute to make sure it's not picking the wrong Datepicker.
desktopModeMediaQuery={'@media (min-width: 480px)'}
This is actually working directly in the Browser, but using Selenium it will always pick the mobile version and this lead to testing failures.
I started selenium with 1920x1080 screen size, and the screenshots provided by Selenium are exactly that size but always showing the mobile picker. Because we using SSR its likely that Selenium using a wrong size somewhere and doesn't get the right code provided.
Is there any way to fix that?
Versions used:
Selenium Standalone 4.10.0
Codeception 5.1.2
Chrome 130.0.6723.116-1 amd64
Thanks for reading!

Reminder to me: Better check your pushed code before you start a thread.
It was exactly the mentioned desktopModeMediaQuery missing in my commit.. silly mistake. I'm sorry!

Make sure you come back and accept your answer so the question isn't left unanswered.
